# Both variables end up having same value when trying to swap them using references

Tags: c++, pointers, reference, pass-by-reference, swap

I'm trying to swap two variables' contents. I did it just fine using pointers. But trying to implement it using references is not working.

```
#include <iostream>

//Implementing a reference based swap
void RefSwap(int& x, int& y)
{
    int extra;
    extra = x; //automatically de-referenced
    x = y;
    y = extra;
}

int main()
{
    int a = 3, b = 10;
    int& ref_a = a, ref_b = b;  //refs don't actually exist in memory, they act like aliases

    RefSwap(ref_a, ref_b);
    std::cout << a << " " << b << std::endl;
}
```

My output:

```
10 10
```

Expected output:

```
10 3
```

Using VS Community 2022

Comment: I believe `ref_b`  is not a reference. Instead its an int and a copy of `b`. Related: [https://ideone.com/Y0PdCh](https://ideone.com/Y0PdCh)

Comment: Sometimes it helps to stick the modifier to the variable name to remind yourself what the modifier applies to `int &ref_a = a, ref_b = b;` Now it's a bit easier to see that `ref_a` is a reference and `ref_b` is not. Not a foolproof system, mind you, but I find it helps.

Comment: thanks both of you, but if do attach the ```&``` to ```int``` itself, shouldn't ```ref_b``` be declared as a reference?

Comment: @Kaiser No, it isn't.

Comment: No matter where you place the the `&` , it applies to the variable. `int& ref_a` `int &ref_a` and `int      &         ref_a`, all the same thing. You get the same thing with pointers. `int * a_ptr, b_not_ptr;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```cpp
int& ref_a = a, ref_b = b;
```

This is

```cpp
int& ref_a = a;
int ref_b = b;
```

Not:

```cpp
int& ref_a = a;
int& ref_b = b;
```

Change:

```cpp
int& ref_a = a, ref_b = b;
```

To:

```cpp
int& ref_a = a;
int& ref_b = b;
```

will produce the correct result.

Comment: why though? isn't ```&``` attached to ```int``` already in my code? Do similar things happen if  declare multiple pointers?

Comment: @Kaiser It will still declate `ref_b` as an `int`, because the `&` effect  `ref_a` only.

Comment: @Kaiser You get the same thing with pointers. That's why style guide always recommend `int *a` than `int* a`

Comment: `int& ref_a = a, & ref_b = b;` would also work, but I sit in the same camp as Newbie and space out the definitions one per line to prevent any confusion.

Comment: Yep, avoid multiple variable declarations, `int a, b = 0` is another easy pitfall to fall into